# How to print out specific content from list with nested dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hi i have got this list with dictionaries

```
[{'first_name': 'Davey', 'last_name': 'McDuck', 'location': "Rob's Office", 'insane': True, 'followers': 12865, 'following': 120, 'weapons': ['wit', 'steely stare', 'devilish good looks'], 'remorse': None}, {'first_name': 'Jim', 'last_name': 'Bob', 'location': 'Turing Lab', 'insane': False, 'followers': 123, 'following': 5000, 'weapons': ['squeak'], 'remorse': None}, {'first_name': 'Celest', 'last_name': '', 'location': 'Throne Room', 'insane': True, 'followers': 40189, 'following': 1, 'weapons': ['politics', 'dance moves', 'chess grandmaster', 'immortality']}]
```

I have got three dictionaries inside this list and I need to print twitter trend of each dictionary i.e twitter followers - following = trend. Also i need to make a en empty list and append these 3 values to that empty list. So far I have got this code below any suggestion plz?

```
trend = []
followers = int(duck_collection['followers']) - int(duck_collection['following'])
for f in followers:
    print(f)
    trend.append(f)
print(trend)
```

the output should be:

```
12745
-4877
40188
Trend: [12745, -4877, 40188]
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What output do you get? What do you expect `followers = int(duck_collection['followers']) - int(duck_collection['following'])` to do?

Comment: Again: You are in my class; this is a class exercise. You can ask me. You have not asked me.

Answer (score 1):

So what I have understood from your question is that you need to store the difference of `followers` and `following` value for each user dictionary and store it in an empty list called `trend`.

You can do it in a few lines using list comprehension as shown here:

```
user_stats = [{'first_name': 'Davey', 'last_name': 'McDuck', 'location': "Rob's Office", 'insane': True, 'followers': 12865, 'following': 120, 'weapons': ['wit', 'steely stare', 'devilish good looks'], 'remorse': None}, {'first_name': 'Jim', 'last_name': 'Bob', 'location': 'Turing Lab', 'insane': False, 'followers': 123, 'following': 5000, 'weapons': ['squeak'], 'remorse': None}, {'first_name': 'Celest', 'last_name': '', 'location': 'Throne Room', 'insane': True, 'followers': 40189, 'following': 1, 'weapons': ['politics', 'dance moves', 'chess grandmaster', 'immortality']}]

trend = [user["followers"] - user["following"] for user in user_stats]
```

Thus you will get your `trend` list.

Comment: looks like it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate over all the items in the list and calculate the trend for each and then append it to the `trend` list.

```
trend = []
for item in duck_collection:
    current_trend = item['followers']-item['following']
    print(current_trend)
    trend.append(current_trend)
print(trend)
```

Alternatively, without printing you can use list comprehension to create the `trend` list -

```
trend = [item['followers']-item['following'] for item in duck_collection]
```

Comment: thank you it worked perfectly

Comment: Hi one more question plz, is there any way if the net followers > 0, print that whole dictionary? i mean trendy ducks = [12745, -4877, 40188], at index [0] is related to davey and [2] is related to Celest. i want to print davey and celest dictionary because their net followers are > 0. looking forward for your response plz

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
l = [{'first_name': 'Davey', 'last_name': 'McDuck', 'location': "Rob's Office", 'insane': True, 'followers': 12865, 'following': 120, 'weapons': ['wit', 'steely stare', 'devilish good looks'], 'remorse': None}, {'first_name': 'Jim', 'last_name': 'Bob', 'location': 'Turing Lab', 'insane': False, 'followers': 123, 'following': 5000, 'weapons': ['squeak'], 'remorse': None}, {'first_name': 'Celest', 'last_name': '', 'location': 'Throne Room', 'insane': True, 'followers': 40189, 'following': 1, 'weapons': ['politics', 'dance moves', 'chess grandmaster', 'immortality']}]
trend = [x['followers'] - x['following'] for x in l]
print(trend)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most readable answer, but a functional approach would be:

```
>>> from operator import sub, itemgetter
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> list(starmap(sub, map(itemgetter('followers', 'following'), duck_collection)))
[12745, -4877, 40188]
```

You could use just `operator.itemgetter` and a comprehension though:

```
[x - y for x, y in map(itemgetter('followers', 'following'), duck_collection)]
```